# Template class member vs. non-member template function ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overload-resolution, template-classes

I'm developing a header-only library for automatic/algorithmic differentiation. The goal is to be able to simply change the type of the variables being fed to a function and calculate first and second derivatives. For this, I've created a template class that allows the programmer to select the storage type for the private data members. Included is a snippet below with an offending operator overload.

```
template <typename storage_t>
class HyperDual
{
    template <typename T> friend class HyperDual;
    public:
        template <typename T>
        HyperDual<storage_t> operator+(const HyperDual<T>& rhs) const
        {
            HyperDual<storage_t> sum;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < this->values.size(); i++)
                sum.values[i] = this->values[i] + rhs.values[i];
            return sum;
        }
    protected:
        std::vector<storage_t> values;
};
```

Later on, to maximize the versatility, I provide template functions to allow interaction.

```
template <typename storage_t, typename T>
HyperDual<storage_t> operator+(const HyperDual<storage_t>& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !(std::is_same<T, char>::value), "RHS must be numeric");
    return HyperDual<storage_t>(lhs.values[0] + rhs);
}

template <typename storage_t, typename T>
HyperDual<storage_t> operator+(const T& lhs, const HyperDual<storage_t>& rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !(std::is_same<T, char>::value), "LHS must be numeric");
    return HyperDual<storage_t>(lhs + rhs.values[0]);
}
```

What I'm encountering is that the compiler is trying to instantiate the second non-member template function.

```
#include "hyperspace.h"

int main()
{
    HyperDual<long double> one(1); // There is an appropriate constructor
    HyperDual<double> two(2);

    one + two;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the static_assert generated error "LHS must be numeric" for this. How would I resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: You provide `operator+=`, but you never declared `operator+(HyperDual<U>, HyperDual<V>)`, you likely needs to declare it. `operator+=` does not give you `operator+` for free.

Comment: If both operands are `HyperDual`, presumably you should want to provide a separate `operator+`, no?

Comment: I copied the wrong function from my code. It was supposed to be the member operator+ function. The question has been updated with the correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found my own issue. It comes down to the difference between static_assert and std::enable_if

Replacing my template declaration and removing static_assert, I achieve equivalent functionality:

```
template <typename storage_t, typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, char>::value>::type>
HyperDual<storage_t> operator+(const T& lhs, const HyperDual<storage_t>& rhs)
{
    return HyperDual<storage_t>(lhs + rhs.value());
}
```

(Small detail, but `rhs.values[0]` was replaced with `rhs.value()`. This had nothing to do with the template issue, but was related to member access.

Answer (score 0):

use `enable_if_t` to make the non-member template can only be applied in the specific context?

```
template <typename storage_t, typename T, typename = enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !(std::is_same<T, char>::value)>>
HyperDual<storage_t> operator+(const HyperDual<storage_t>& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !(std::is_same<T, char>::value), "RHS must be numeric");
    return HyperDual<storage_t>(lhs.values[0] + rhs);
}
```

the `static_assert` may be duplicated here.